# Create Type of Region Plug-In based on "List" Type of Region

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I need to create a `Type` of `Region` `Plug-In` based on `List` `Type` of `Region`.

Standard `List` gets a `List` `Navigation` `Shared Component` and creates, for example, `Card` elements as `a` HTML tags with some `href` defined in the chosen `Shared Component: List`.  But I need the ability to redefine all `a` elements as `button` elements and give them custom CSS classes and HTML attributes for each child element of a `List` region (for each `button`), not the `List` region itself. For example, to create a `Menu Popup` `Card` in the similar way as for a `button` ([as described in this tutorial](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:1306:::NO:::)).

But I could not find any way to create a Plug-In with `List` settings by default but with ability to edit and add custom settings for my plug-in. Neither I found any existing plug-ins in community.

How to do it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create a plug-in. If you need a custom `Cards` template for a region with `List` type, then go to `Shared Components > User Interface > Templates` and create it there as copy of `Cards`, then edit.

Damn it, why APEX is so hard to google? :D